# 「助かりました」と「助かります」の違い？

Tags: expressions

When to use 「助かります」, when to use 「助かりました」?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/384/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20966/7810

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before and after receiving help?

- A-San: This sofa is heavy
- B-San: I'll grab the other end
- A-San: 助かります　(effectively, "that would be helpful")

vs after from same situation above they finish moving the sofa

- A-San: ありがとう！助かりました。
- B-San: どう致しまして

A similar situation for the first.

- A-San: I'm going out in the snow
- B-San: I have some gloves I could loan you
- A-San: 借りていいの？助かります　(It's okay to borrow them? That would be helpful)

Then later when A-San gets back

- A-San: この手袋はとても暖かった。助かりました。(these gloves were super warm, they/you were helpful)
- B-San: よかったです。いつでも借りていいよ。(effectively: glad it worked out, you can borrow them anytime)